# unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path for windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, docker, spring-boot

I created `Dockerfile.txt` under `C:\Users\user_name\` dir.

File contents are :

```
FROM centos

RUN yum install -y java

VOLUME /tmp
ADD /test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar myapp.jar
RUN sh -c 'touch /myapp.jar'
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar", "/myapp.jar"]
```

I moved Dockerfile and uber jar under `C:\Users\user_name\` and executed command in PowerShell under `C:\Users\user_name\`.

```
docker build -t spring-boot-docker .
```

I am getting this error :

> unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile
>   path: GetFileAttributesEx C:\Users\user_name\Dockerfile: The system
>   cannot find the file specified.

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: `Dockerfile` not `Dockerfile.txt`

Comment: `docker build -t spring-boot-docker -f Dockerfile.txt .`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`docker` will default to a file named `Dockerfile` with no extension. Since you named your Dockerfile `Dockerfile.txt`, you have to provide that with the `-f` flag.

```
docker build -t spring-boot-docker -f Dockerfile.txt .
```

Comment: After moving jar and Dockerfile.txt in new directory and running command "docker build -t spring-boot-docker -f .\Dockerfile.txt ." in PowerShell under new directory did the trick for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I named the file  `Dockerfile` (in Git CMD under Windows) and the result was

> `docker build .`
>
> `unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: GetFileAttributesEx C:\*windows-path*\Dockerfile: The system cannot find the file specified.`

So I change it form `Dockerfile` to `Dockerfile.txt` and used `-f` option:

> `docker build -t test_image -f ".\Dockerfile.txt" .`

And it worked :)